# Webiopi no auto start with relay

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, webiopi

i have this index.html and i have connected my raspberry pi with a module relay. The problem is that when i open the site for using buttons, it starts like the button being already hitted. i want to send the signal to the relay when i click the button. what should i change?

```
webiopi().ready(function() {

                webiopi().setFunction(7,"out");
                var content, button;
                content = $("#content");

                button = webiopi().createGPIOButton(7, "SWITCH");
                content.append(button);
                webiopi().refreshGPIO(true);              
});
```

Comment: Did you try doing a **[gpio reset](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/the-gpio-utility/)** first?

Comment: hmmm how can i do that? im not an expert! now im learning... can u tell me how to do it?

Comment: Yes, you're welcome! First, follow [this tutorial](http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/). Then, come back for more tips ... Sorry for delay.

Comment: ok i did the tutorial! what's next mate?

Comment: Now, you can use **gpio reset**. Try it before using relay:
http://goo.gl/nYImwP

Comment: Did it work? Any news? Did you see this [picture](http://goo.gl/nYImwP)?

Comment: i just checked it, no it didnt work unfortunately... it still does that thing... its killing me...

Answer (score 0):

I bet your relay is triggered by a LOW state, you can initalize the pins to high or low with Webiopi, edit the /etc/webiopi/config file and set PIN7 to High at startup, the documentation is here http://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/CONFIGURATION.